# How to fix this stretched texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, uv

I try to apply this material on my object but I can't figure out how to fix this stretched texture.

- as you can see in the screen, i use Blender v2.79
- my meshes are unwrapped on the only existing UV map
- I deleted and recreated the material
- I had this on other scenes in the past few days

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What does the original texture look like? I'm guessing it's an image texture and thus should be using the image texture node and not the environment texture node.

Comment: When you converted your text to a mesh it is best to do a limited dissolve and remove doubles. Your mesh has a lot of bad topology. I would recommend watching this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxDOhxjdFOs&t=239s also fix what Brenticus said above.

Comment: @Brenticus please put your comment into an answer so this case can be closed

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have the wrong texture node. From what I can tell you are trying to use an image texture in an environment texture node. If you switch the environment texture nodes to image texture nodes everything should work.

Comment: That was indeed the origin of my problem, did not even noticed it. Thank you.